# Alternative to accessing classes from within classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm having real problems getting my head around classes, and am hoping someone can answer my (very basic!) question

I have a mysql class allowing me to setup a mysql connection, perform queries and other related mysql functions.

I've got a database setup with a parent\child structure, and have a recursive function (my createNode function) that outputs a set of nested lists reflecting the parent\child structure.

The createNode function instantiates the mysql class on every recursion in order to query the required data from the database.

Ideally I would like to put this createNode function into a class, but I understand it is bad practise to instantiate one class into another class, however I can't see any way around this.

How can I structure my classes to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, **it's not bad practice** to instantiate a class within another one (see Factory pattern, per example). However, in that particular case, you could just pass the MySQL class to the constructor of the NodeCreator class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Noder {
  private $_conn;
  public function __construct($mysql_connection)
  {
    $this->_conn = $mysql_connection;
  }
  public function createNode()
  {
    // whatever you do
  }
}
$mysql = new Mysql();
$noder = new Noder($mysql);
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was saying in my comment above. :) You could also (and probably should) type hint to the `Mysql` type.

Comment: Thanks both scragz and netcoder for your super rapid responses, much appreciated! Code example is great, as is your description netcoder. This makes good sense to me :-) I'll try it out now.